# How do I use freetype bindings in Rust?

Tags: rust, fonts, handle, freetype

I've been working on a fairly basic project which needs to interact with fonts. The plan was to use the bindings for [FreeType by the Servo team](https://crates.io/crates/freetype). However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how exactly one is to use it. I've new to FreeType, so I'm following their [tutorial](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html#section-7). What's tripping me up at this point is creating the handles. I did try the (admittedly laughable) to create the library handle for instance:

```
use freetype::freetype;
let library: freetype::FT_Library;
```

That predictably did not work. I have resolved to use `font_kit` for the project because I'm fairly certain this is a bit over my head. But I'd still love to find out how I can actually do this.

Comment: Have you tried [freetype::freetype::FT_Init_FreeType](https://doc.servo.org/freetype/freetype/fn.FT_Init_FreeType.html)?

Comment: In order to call that function, I need to supply a pointer to the FT_Library type. That's where I'm stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can use `std::ptr::null_mut` to initialize `freetype::freetype::FT_Library`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut lib: freetype::freetype::FT_Library = std::ptr::null_mut();
    let result = unsafe {
        freetype::freetype::FT_Init_FreeType(&mut lib)
    };
    println!("Initialization succeed:{}",  freetype::succeeded(result));
}
```

Based on [example](https://github.com/servo/webrender/blob/e306d6223f6c96252147c16cff94ac63fb9764f5/webrender/src/platform/unix/font.rs#L327).

Comment: Sorry about the long delay between question and reply, but this is the proper answer and it works as intended!

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing font processing in Rust, [`read-fonts`](https://docs.rs/read-fonts/latest/read_fonts/) and [`skrifa`](https://docs.rs/skrifa/latest/skrifa/) from the Fontations project might be interesting to you. There is an advantage in safety and Rust ergonomics in using these pure Rust libraries.